# django filter two ManyToManyField equal

Tags: django, django-filter

```
class VideoUserModel(models.Model):
    user = models.ManyToManyField(get_user_model())
    viewlist = models.ManyToManyField(get_user_model(), related_name='view_list', blank=True, null=True)
```

I want to get the queryset of `user` list equal `viewlist`.
How to do this?
`VideoUserModel.objects.all().filter(user=**viewlist**)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no trivial answer to that. We can do this by counting the number of `nuser`s, the number of items in the `viewlist` relation and the number of items in `user` that are also in `nuser` and then check if these three are all equal:

```
from django.db.models import Count, F, Q

VideoUserModel.objects.annotate(
    nuser=Count('user', distinct=True),
    nview=Count('viewlist', distinct=True),
    nuserfilter=Count('user', filter=Q(user=F('viewlist')), distinct=True)
).filter(
    nuser=F('nview'),
    nview=F('nuserfilter')
)
```

---

> **Note**: It is normally better to make use of the [**`settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#std:setting-AUTH_USER_MODEL) to refer to the user model, than to work with the [**`get_user_model()`** method [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/#django.contrib.auth.get_user_model), since that requires loading the `auth` app before the current app. For more information you can see the [*referencing the `User` model* section of the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/#referencing-the-user-model).